# Django API: How to get all objects that match certain value in UUID field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

When trying to query objects on their foreignkey field, I don't manage to get any details. The company ID is and uuid (uuid4) field.

I have a Model called "contacts":

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to get all Contacts, that work for the same company. Therefore I have created a ListAPIView whitin views.py
Views.py

```py
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer


class CompanyContactsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        company = self.kwargs['company']
        return Contact.objects.filter(company=company)
```

And to get a URL I added the path in urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('contacts/<uuid:company>/', CompanyContactsListView.as_view(), name='contacts')
]
```

Problem is, that when i try to go for that path and enter an UUID of an company that exists and has related contacts, I get the following error

```py
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Is it possible, that my URL is wrong and therefore cant query the ListAPIView?
Because I want result like that:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "Joshuah",
        "lastname": "Bankhurst",
        "company": "e871c47b-9b91-4cf9-94a6-e8135510c11d"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "Clayborn",
        "lastname": "Sylett",
        "company": "e871c47b-9b91-4cf9-94a6-e8135510c11d"
    }
]
```

**EDIT**:

- I am trying to access the endpoint on **contacts/e871c47b-9b91-4cf9-94a6-e8135510c11d**

-This is model of company:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    about = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Company"
        verbose_name_plural = "Companys"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Comment: How you are requesting the endpoint?

Comment: share the company model details

Comment: Hi, did add endpoint and company model in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the query is not matching the uuid pk field in the get queryset method.  Assuming that the company uuid is being passed in the kwargs, the query should match on the pk of the Company model.

CompanyContactsListView was not getting called, because the urls path `/contacts/` was matching on the router, not the view class.
Lets also change the param name in the kwargs to be more explict. `company_uuid`

company/urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("companys", CompanyViewSet)
router.register("benefits", BenefitsViewSet)
router.register("contacts", ContactViewSet)
router.register("jobpost", JobpostViewset)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('contact-list/<uuid:company_uuid>/', CompanyContactsListView.as_view(), name='contacts'),
]
```

contract_viewset.py

```
class CompanyContactsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        company_uuid = self.kwargs['company_uuid']
        return Contact.objects.filter(company__id=company_uuid)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt work for me. When trying to access the instances which match the uuid (ForeignKey) of company, I get back: ``` {
    "detail": "Not found."
} ``` I try to access it vial /contacts/3e3111a4-76da-4e1d-9ede-ee449dc63009/

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the edited version doesn`t work for me too :(

Comment: Not sure what the Company model looks like, you might try using the double underscore, "dunder", style foreign key query. Contact.objects.filter(company__uuid=company_uuid)

Comment: "Dunder" didn't work. I added the company model in my initial question. Thanks!

Comment: Try Contact.objects.filter(company__id=company_uuid),  The custom pk on the Company model is what the query is trying to match the 'company' var in the kwargs.

Comment: I added the code to GitHub: https://github.com/kruppy/endpoint_test

Comment: Contact.objects.filter(company__id=company_uuid) doesn't work either, is it generally possible to query for foreignkey or am I just trying something unachievable?

Comment: This is very achievable. It is almost verbatim from the DRF documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url  I noticed that there might be other errors in the models somewhere. Running the example code results in "no such table: company_company". Does the django admin work?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I followed the linked documentation when trying to create my solution. In my case, the admin works on my machine

Comment: I was able to run this and get the desired results. Is this working for you now?

Comment: No. Did you get a list of contacts on '/company/contacts/:company_id'? I still get the 404.

Comment: The company/urls.py needs to be changed, see the edit in the answer. 
/api/company/contact-list/<UUID>/
The url '/company/contacts/' conflicts with the default drf routing.